# Extension Methods for Inner Class?

Tags: scala, extension-methods, inner-classes, dependent-type, scala-3

Is it possible to define an extension method for an inner class? The [syntax reference](https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/syntax.html) seems to show it is possible to have a `UsingParamClause` *before* the `DefParam`, which is promising, and motivates the following example:

```
class Foo:
  class Bar

extension (using foo: Foo)(bar: foo.Bar) def baz: String = "hi"

val myFoo: Foo = new Foo
val myBar: myFoo.Bar = new myFoo.Bar

val str: String = myBar.baz()
```

The last line gives me the following error:

```
value baz is not a member of myFoo.Bar.
An extension method was tried, but could not be fully constructed:

    baz(/* missing */summon[Foo])(myBar)

    failed with:

        No given instance of type Foo was found for parameter foo of method baz
```

I would expect that `myFoo` would be a suitable given instance of type `Foo`. Do I need to use a given instance?

Comment: Try `given val myFoo: Foo = new Foo`.  Only `given`s can be summoned for `using`.